# Integration Test Data Set Up in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-test, spring-boot-test

Here is my test class

```java
    @SpringBootTest
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    public MyTest {

       ...

       @Before
       public void init() {
          System.out.println(":::: --- start init() ---");
          ...
        }
       ...
    }
```

Strange enough, the `init()` won't run for some reason. If I change the `@Before` to `@BeforeAll` and the method to static, the `init()` will run. A problem is that those data set up code doesn't run inside a static method and I can't change all of them to run inside a static block. For now, I have the following code in each test method to overcome the issue

```java
    if(list.size() == 0)
       init();
```

I am wondering why the `@Before` won't run. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JUnit 5, `@BeforeEach` and `@BeforeAll` annotations are the equivalents for `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` in JUnit 4.

`@Before` is a JUnit 4 annotation, while `@BeforeAll` is a JUnit 5 annotation. You can also see this from the imports `org.junit.Before` and `org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll`.

Also, the code marked `@BeforeEach` is executed before each test, while `@BeforeAll` runs once before the entire test fixture.

To be able to run `@BeforeAll` on a non-static method you can change the lifecycle of the the test instance with:

```java
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
```

You have to be careful though, since the test class instance is now only created once, and not once per test method. If your test methods rely on state stored in instance variables, you may now need to manually reset the state in `@BeforeEach` or `@AfterEach` lifecycle methods.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems that Spring 2.4.M comes with both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5. For this case, I only need to set up data once for entire test fixture. As @BeforeAll with a static method, I need to figure out how to involk non-static method.

Comment: If you want to run it once without a static method, you can change the test instance lifecycle with @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS). You have to be careful with your state management though, since now it won't re-create the test class per method. I will alter my answer to include this information.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I am wondering why the annotation requests a static method. To work around the restriction, I am thinking of creating an inter class with a method to wrap around data initialization.

Comment: Check out the JUnit 5 documentation about test lifecycle, it’s what they recommend: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for your additional information again. The data setup portion of my test is for populating test data for read only usage. So, there isn't a state issue for those test.